# submitting webforms from multiple sites into my lead management system

Tags: php

I m working on a lead management system , which is supposed to store property information(for sale) as a lead.
So far I have given the feature to create a new lead in the system for the owner , where he enters details of the property and a new record in created in the db.

Now what is required in reality is:
there are many different sites with forms on them that collect the property information.
Client wants that we should generate a code to be put on these sites so that the information entered in those forms is also saved in out lead management system.
I believe I would need to provide a curl code to be placed in those sites.Please correct me if I am wrong.
Another issue is all those forms on these sites have their own field names and there is no way to map those field names with the field names in our database.
Can anyone suggest what options do I have?

Comment: [You want to make an API](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/how-to-create-an-api-10-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe this helps anyway:

PHP stores everything that has been sent via HTTP POST in the `$_POST` variable. By using `array_keys($_POST)` you can get an array that contains all the names of the form fields that were sent to the script.

Determining what the different fields represent is pretty much impossible, of course. So if you want to store everything that was sent to your script, you would need a table containing and id and maybe a date or something describing the supplier of the information. They you create a second table with id, key and value. For every field sent to your script you then create an entry in this table and use the ID to link them together.

A much better solution in this case would be to use a NoSQL database, of course.

Comment: If the fields names are always different BUT have the same content, you could ask the client to create an hidden field with the field name in order of what you want.. exmeple if you want name and last name your hidden input value will be "namefield,lastnamefield", etc.

Comment: Thanks for you response.
We have decided to give option to for a person to map the fields in our DB , manually with the form fields by giving them an interface for mapping.So whenever a post data comes we know what all fields to map to which fields in our DB.

Comment: @David
Thats a very good option I think.It ll work perfect.I ll try and update here.Thanks for the great thought.

Comment: Hidden output will always have the same name plus you will have all the field name in order ... just have to parse the field after and loop in $_POST

Comment: There is a case though where there might be other hidden fields already in that form and hence might affect the order.